# Trigger PHP-CLI via webrowser

Tags: php, apache, rest, webhooks

I am trying to trigger a php script to start when a webhook is received. I am able to get the script to start but it will only run for 45-60 seconds before it quits. I understand that this is because the browser session has timed out. How do i get a script to run and continue running after the browswer session expires. 
so far 
I have tried

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
$command2 = "nohup /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/MLS.php >> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/paging.log &";
shell_exec($command2);
```

to no avail. I have tried modifying the max_execution_time in PHP.ini as well

I have also tried using the command

```
pclose(popen($command2,'r'));
```

with no luck.

Any advice is appreciated.

*** UPDATE *****

SOLVED.. Sorry for not stating the system that I am working on . It is linux. The command that ended up working was 
`$command2 ="nohup php MLS.php >> paging.log &";`

Thanks for all the help

Comment: there is no time limit by default for php scripts called by the command line, i suspect something else is happening. paging.log contains? have you tried running the command from the  command line manually?

Comment: If you are running in Linux, you can spawn it off as a Background process and it will run until it finishes. You can do this in Windows also, but it is less straightforward. On Linux, redirect output to a file and add "&" to the end of the command line. E.g. $command2 = "php program.php > /tmp/output.txt &"; Of course, don't expect the Web Server to know when it has results. The command could take weeks to run, and the Web Server can not wait.

Comment: if? look at the command line, does windows know what *nohup* is? you dont seem to haven even looked at his code it has everything you say it should @UncaAlby

Comment: No, Windows does not know what "nohup" is. I'll admit I did not study the OP code in depth, however, nowhere does the OP state whether he's running Linux or Windows. Put simply, if he's running Windows, what he put in his question will NOT Work. Search the Web for "spawn background php process in windows". There are a number of tutorial sites that come up, including a StackOverflow answer.